# Universal completions of *algebras

Tags: functional-analysis, representation-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, quantum-groups

I am dealing with two "universal completions" but I am not sure if they are the same thing and would appreciate some guidance.

1. Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a unital *-algebra. A $\mathrm{C}^*$-seminorm on a $\mathcal{A}$ is a seminorm $p:\mathcal{A}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^+$ that satisfies, for all $a,\,b\in\mathcal{A}$:

$$p(ab)\leq p(a)p(b)\text{ and }p(a^*a)=p(a)^2.$$

We get a 'large' (pre?)-$\mathrm{C}^*$-norm by taking:

$$a\mapsto \|a\|_{u_1}:=\sup\{p(a)\mid p\text{ is a $\mathrm{C}^*$-seminorm on $\mathcal{A}$}\}.$$
Denote $A_{u_1}$ the corresponding norm-completion of $\mathcal{A}$.

2. $\mathcal{A}$ as before, for $H$ Hilbert space*s*, another 'large' (pre?)-$\mathrm{C}^*$-norm:

$$a\mapsto \|a\|_{u_2}:=\sup\{\|\pi(a)\|\mid\pi:\mathcal{A}\rightarrow B(H),\text{ a unital *-homomorphism}\}.$$

Denote $A_{u_2}$ the corresponding norm-completion of $\mathcal{A}$.

> Question: Are these two norms (and hence $\mathrm{C}^*$-algebras) the same thing?

Comment: I remmeberd this question recently and should remark that the definitions of $u_1$ and $u_2$ do not necessarily work, ie you may have elements of infinite norm. The proof below still works in showing that $u_1$ and $u_2$ agree, but these are not necessarily the correct universal completions. What is better is to look at the directed system of $C^*$ semi-norms and take the projective limit of the associated quotients or the Hausdorff completion of the system (you get the same thing)- what you get is called a "locally $C^*$ algebra" or a "pro-C*-algebra".

Comment: An example where it doesn't work is $\Bbb C[x]$, here any evaluation of the value $x$ induces a semi-norm, in particular you get that $\|a\|_{u_1}=\infty = \|a\|_{u_2}$ whenever $a$ is not proportional to $1$. The locally $C^*$ completion of $\Bbb C[x]$ should be $C(\Bbb R)$

Comment: That you @s.harp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remark: The Hilbert space $H$ should vary as well when taking the supremum, otherwise the two can be different and you generally only have (depending on what $H$ you chose) $\|\cdot\|_{u_2}≤\|\cdot\|_{u_1}$.

Suppose $p$ is a non-zero $C^*$ semi-norm. The zero locus of $p$ is a two-sided $*$ ideal, as such $\mathcal A/N(p)$ is also a unital $*$-algebra, if we complete it then $p$ makes it into a $C^*$-algebra. By using for example the GNS construction you find a Hilbert space $H$ and an injective unital representation $\pi:\overline{\mathcal A/N(p)}\to B(H)$. Injective $*$-morphisms are isometric for $C^*$-algebras so you have $$p(a) = p([a]) = \|\pi([a])\|$$
so the representation $\mathcal A\to B(H)$, $a\mapsto \pi([a])$ is a unital isometric $*$ representation if you give $\mathcal A$ the $C^*$ semi-norm $p$.

Conclusion: Every $C^*$ semi-norm comes from a unital representation to operators on a Hilbert space, as such the two sets over which you take the supremum are the same.

Comment: Thank you very much.