# Does every complex involutive algebra admit at least one non-trivial C*-seminorm?

Tags: abstract-algebra, functional-analysis, involutions

Let $A$ be a unital involutive algebra over $\mathbb{C}$. A $C^*$-seminorm is a seminorm $p$ such that $p(x^*x) = p(x)^2, \forall x \in A$.

I understand that if the spectral radius of $x \in A$ given by $\sup \{ |\lambda| \in \mathbb{C} : x - \lambda \mathbb{1} \text{ is not invertible} \}$ is a seminorm (i.e. real-valued) then this is a $C^*$-seminorm on $A$.

I also understand that if $\pi$ is a unital $^*$-representation of $A$, then $x \rightarrow || \pi(x)||$, where $|| \cdot||$ is the operator norm associated with $\pi$, is a $C^*$-seminorm on $A$.

But what about the case where the spectral radius of $A$ is not real valued? Does there still exist a non-trivial $C^*$-seminorm on $A$? Or does there always exist a non-trivial $^*$-representation of $A$?

Comment: The spectral radius (by your definition!) is always real-valued. It is the sup of a set of real numbers.

Comment: @diracdeltafunk unfortunately the supremum of a set of real numbers is not always real, since it can be infinite if the set is unbounded, and indeed the spectrum of an element of a *-algebra can be unbounded.

Comment: Oh sorry, I misunderstood your concern there! Nevermind

Answer (score 0):

It appears the answer is negative. In Fragoulopoulou's Topological Algebras with Involution Section 14.(2), for example, a unital $^*$-algebra with no non-trivial positive linear forms is given. Since every $^*$-representation is associated with a positive linear form, this $^*$-algebra has no non-trivial $^*$-representations. And since every non-trivial $C^*$-seminorm gives a non-trivial $^*$-representation (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3720491/universal-completions-of-algebras?rq=1)), then this algebra must not admit any non-trivial $C^*$-seminorms.